# redirecting the request not complete in php user authentication

Tags: php

I have this public function for check Admin Authentication access:

```
class Auth {

public static function checkAdminAuthentication()
 {
    // initialize the session (if not initialized yet)
    Session::init();

    // self::checkSessionConcurrency();

    // if user is not logged in or is not an admin (= not role type 7)
    if (!Session::userIsLoggedIn() || Session::get("user_account_type") != 7) {

        // ... then treat user as "not logged in", destroy session, redirect to login page
        Session::destroy();
        header('location: ' . Config::get('URL') . 'admin/login');
        exit();
    }
}
```

and admin controller class is:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Construct this object by extending the basic Controller class
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // special authentication check for the entire controller: Note the check-ADMIN-authentication!
        // All methods inside this controller are only accessible for admins (= users that have role type 7)
        Auth::checkAdminAuthentication();
    }

    /**
     * This method controls what happens when you move to /admin or /admin/index in your app.
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $this->Language->load('common/dashboard'); 

        $data['header'] = $this->Language->get('heading_title');  

        $this->View->render('admin/index','admin', array(
                'users' => UserModel::getPublicProfilesOfAllUsers(),
                'header' =>  $this->Language->get('heading_title'),

            )
        );
    }

    public function login()
    {

        $this->Language->load('common/dashboard'); 

        $data['header'] = $this->Language->get('heading_title');  

        $this->View->render('admin/login','admin', array(
                'header' =>  $this->Language->get('heading_title'),

            )
        );

    }
}
```

Now In action I see Error and redirect not complete for me :

> >
>   "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."

How do fix this error?!

Comment: It's because you are creating an endless loop with redirects. Your constructor is always calling the procedural authentication-check function, which always redirect to executing the same constructor again.

Comment: @tereško: You right! But better way is? if i change only template(ie: login page - dashboard) without redirect to another page this way is true?

Comment: For a very bare-bones version, you can try looking at how it was done in [this example](https://github.com/teresko/blank/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to exclude `login()` from this check (by moving it to different controller or something) or it will redirect indefinitely:

- before `login()` route is being called, `__construct` is called
- `__construct()` redirects to `login()`
- before `login()` route is being called, `__construct` is called
- etc..